# How many log files will generate for apex batch job run?

Tags: apex, batch, debugging

I am running a batch job on the `Account` object which has around 104810 records, and I set the batch size to 10000. After the batch job finishes, I can see around 20 log files generated.

Is there any logic behind how many logs will generated? Is there any relation with number of batch?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you get a log for each of:

- `start`
- `execute`
- `finish`

Given you have a batch size of 10,000 and a total recordset of 104,810 I would expect to see the following:

- 1 x `start` log
- 11 x `execute` log (10 x 10,000 = 100,000, then one additional one for the remaining 4,810)
- 1 x `finish`